# Yii рендер Layout внутри CController

Tags: php, yii

Контроллер для сайта общий (для шаблонов), так вот, шаблон у меня сборный, состоит из множества блоков которые можно вкл./выкл. на любой из страниц.

Пример:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
   public $blockTopSlider = false;
   public $blockBussinesPreview = false;
   .... и т.д. ....

   .... тут дальше идет код ....
}
```

в `SiteController` для главной страницы все как обычно.

```
function actionIndex()
{
   $this->blockTopSlider = true;
   $this->blockBussinesPreview =true;

   // Как мне тут отрендерить этот шаблон без представлений
   //т.е если я сделаю так
   $this->render("index");
   // то будет все работать, но сам файл index.php при этом у меня совершенно пустой.
}
```